# Remove preprocessor definitions in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I am getting this error in CMAKE

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h(2988)
: error C2338: 'CAtlExeModuleT' must be used with neither _WINDLL nor _USRDLL defined

I have tried remove_definitions("-D_WINDLL") but still getting the same error and when I open the solution generated in CMAKETemp I find _WINDLL added in inherited values of preprocessor definition tab (Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->preprocessor definitions)

Comment: Have you tried adding the explicit "undefine" to the command line: `-U_WINDLL` ?

Comment: no. How can i do that I have never done it before

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you add some description to your question describing what you are trying to do and how your current CMakeLists.txt file looks like? Otherwise it's hard to say what may cause the error you are seeing.